# Inappropriately specific default profile

Tags: feature-request, profile-page, network-profile

My first involvement in SE was to join math.SE, and I wrote a profile sentence about mathematics in my life. I've since joined numerous other SE communities, and in each one my profile is automatically copied from math.SE, rather than from my (obviously more generic) Network Profile. Is this the result of a preference setting somewhere, or am I doomed to erase my mathematical profile every time I join a SE community forevermore?

As this has been asked before, I am invited to click “That solved my problem!” — but the problem is still there. As suggested in answer to the old question, I'll change the “bug” tag to “feature-request”; and also ask why, by design, the oldest profile outranks the network profile.

Comment: So, what you really want is a way to set which profile is your "master" profile?

Comment: That's a fair way to put it, yes.

Comment: Unless the last part – “why, by design, the oldest profile outranks the network profile” – has been asked and answered, this is not a duplicate.